# Will accessing an element within a list annotated with @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA) cause initializing the entire list?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I have the following Chat class:

```
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Chat extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user1_id")
    private User user1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user2_id")
    private User user2;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    @OrderBy("sentAt DESC")
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "chat", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();

    public Chat(User user1, User user2) {
        this.user1 = user1;
        this.user2 = user2;
    }
}
```

In respect of the `messages` field, I am only interested in accessing the first element, -which is the latest message this case-

Would executing the following statement: `chat.getMessages().get(0)` cause the entire `messages` list to be initialized? If yes, then what is the best practice?

Answer (score 2):

It will not work in this way.

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#fetching-LazyCollection):

> `LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA` only works for ordered collections, either List(s) that are annotated with `@OrderColumn` or Map(s).
>
> For bags (e.g. regular List(s) of entities that do not preserve any certain ordering), the `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` behaves like any other `FetchType.LAZY` collection (the collection is fetched entirely upon being accessed for the first time).

From the other side, according to the documentation for the [@OrderColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/OrderColumn.html) annotation:

> The `OrderBy` annotation should be used for ordering that is visible as persistent state and maintained by the application. *The `OrderBy` annotation is not used when `OrderColumn` is specified.*
>
> *The order column must be of integral type.* The persistence provider maintains a contiguous (non-sparse) ordering of the values of the order column when updating the association or element collection. The order column value for the first element is 0.

So, you can not use the `@OrderColumn` annotation for ordering by date/time and as result the `LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA` for the first element lazy loading.

I would suggest you to use a separate query for the fetching of the last chat message.